# create new object from existing object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to create a object in a format using javascript.
Below function works but got stuck in creating a object in below format

Tried

```
function changeData(str){
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

var result = Object.values(list.items).map(e=>changeData(e));
```

Inputs

```
var list = {
 "items": {
   "TR": "trans",
   "FU": "fund",
   "IN":  "insta"
  }
}
```

Output

```
"newitem": {
   "TR": "Trans",
   "FU": "Fund",
   "IN":  "Insta"
  }
```

Comment: Why not just making a `for in` loop and changing every value?
If you are using babel or if you can add a polyfill, you could also do something like 
`Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(list.items).map(([key, balue] => [key, changeData(value)]))`

Answer (score 0):

`map` is going to give you an array, not an object. You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead to give you an object:

```
var result = Object.keys(list.items).reduce((a,k)=> { 
  a[k] = changeData(list.items[k]); 
  return a; 
}, {});
```

You could also use `for` or `forEach` if you prefer, but `reduce` saves you a line or two of code.